# Record video to timeline during playback

Tags: video-recording, playback

Is there a video editing software that allows you to record video from a tethered device (like a webcam) directly to the timeline while the project preview is playing back?  This would basically be like if Audacity also allowed video recording and editing.

I would like to be able to record video directly to the timeline at a specific time so that the video and audio will automatically match up rather than recording the video separately, importing it, dragging it to the timeline and trying to line it up.

Answer (score 1):

DaVinci Resolve, Premiere, and FCPX all support direct video capture.  But depending on your hardware configuration, operating system, and camera, you will most likely need a video capture card or external capture device also.

Most computers don't come with a way to get *video* into them, they come with ways to get *data* into them.  HDMI ports are one-way, so you need an HDMI or SDI input, or a way to convert HDMI/SDI to data, and bring it in through USB, Thunderbolt, or PCIe, etc.  Webcams, whether internal or external will need a software driver to communicate to the NLE.  Generally, inbuilt webcams come with their own recording software, and computer manufacturers (hopefully) guard access to the camera. So for built-in webcams, you will need software which has access to your computer's hardware.  As Far as I know, FCPX can access FaceTime cameras, but Resolve and Premiere cannot.  For tethered ones, you'll need drivers supplied by the webcam manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

So basically a Live Broadcast program.

I think a better way is to use timecode. This will automatically line up your video and audio

Comment: How would that automatically line it up?  Wouldn't I still have to line it up myself using the timecodes?